# How will I address this is this a cicd/pipeline problem or program.cs or the launchsettings.json file

Tags: rest, entity-framework-core, swagger, openapi

[image]This api-rafimfi-delinquencymonitoringsv-sbx-sea-1.azurewebsites.net page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://api-rafimfi-delinquencymonitoringsv-sbx-sea-1.azurewebsites.net/
HTTP ERROR 404 but when i add /swagger at the end of the link it appears and displays but when it doesnt have the /swagger it does not appear i do not wish to need the /swagger at the end to open it.

Comment: because its API, you need to specify endpoint. Try this `https://api-rafimfi-delinquencymonitoringsv-sbx-sea-1.azurewebsites.net/api/client`
only endpoint with GET will work in browser, to invoke other methods like POST, DELETE use tools like Postman. Even swagger is easy to use tool to to invoke endpoints

Comment: what files do i need to check